# Remove selected object from variable

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with shopping cart i am building. One part of the code is not working properly and i cant find the option in JS to help me solve this problem. Buying and removing button working but the problem comes when the user removes one dish and after that adds more. Removed dish is reprinted again because it is allready stored in variable "printingDishTxt". Im trying to find solution that removes the dish from the variable ".printingDishTxt"

Do you have any suggestion to achieve such functionality?

Thank you in advance

Code i am using:

```
//Every time user click .button-buy the chosen dish is printing in shopping cart

document.querySelectorAll(".button-buy").forEach(button =>{
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{

      printingDishTxt+=`
      <div>
      <p>"printing name"</p>

      <div>
      <p>"printing price"</p>
      <a class="remove-button "><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
      </div>
      </div>
      `
      dishes.innerHTML=printingDishTxt;

//Every time user click the .remove-button the chosen dish is removing

        document.querySelectorAll(".remove-button").forEach(remove=>{
          remove.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{

              e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

          });
        });

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you rethink of the implementation and:

1. Create a separate variable (e.g. `store`) that will store all the dishes which were added to the cart (with it`s identifiers, if there is no specific id, you can create a random one when you add it to the cart)
2. Implement a function that serializes your cart items in HTML
3. On a remove button click you will need:

   - remove the element from your `store` variable
   - recompute HTML using the function implemented in #2

Comment: Thank you for answer @Andrii Dobrianskiy.
If i am understanding right variable "store" should be a array and every dish a object in that array? Also, "serialize" is something new for me. Are we talking about function that only print cart items? Because i see on google that serialization in JS helping with translation into a format suitable for storage.. Im not sure if i understood it right and if you are thinking about something like that. Again thank you for your time and answer

Comment: 1. If i am understanding right variable "store" should be a array and every dish a object in that array?
- Yes, the store variable will be an array of objects.


2. Also, "serialize" is something new for me. Are we talking about function that only print cart items?
- Yeah, in your case it will be a function that takes a store as a parameter and returns an HTML string that represents this store.

Comment: Hi again. 
I will try to do it that way. Thank you again Andrii :)